# HKWorkoutRouteBuilder adding heart rate data

Tags: ios, core-location, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am using a `HKWorkoutRouteBuilder` to insert route data and then finally save the route and data to `HealthKit`. This all works fine, but I would also like to get heart rate data from the Apple Watch and save that to `HealthKit` at the same time.

**My question is, to save heart rate data, would I save that as metadata? If so, how do I get the current heart rate from the watch and what metadata key would be used?**

Comment: It isn't meta data.  Meta data is just arbitrary values you can associate with the workout.  First, if you want to collect route and heart rate it is much simpler if you create a workout app for the watch. However, it can be done for iOS.  You need to create a `HKWorkoutBuilder` as well as your `HKWorkoutRouteBuilder`.  You then need to set up a persistent query against HealthKit for heart rate samples.  Each time you get a new heart rate sample you add it to the workout builder.  Once you end and save the workout from the builder, you can end your route builder and add it to the workout.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you post this as an answer possible with some sample code?